# How to reference "this" in polymer expression

Tags: polymer

I want to pass the current polymer element as an attribute to another element.  Using {{this}} returns null.  Is there a supported way to access the value of "this" other than creating an attribute that returns the value

Example

```
<polymer-element name='my-el'>
  <template>
    <sub-element target={{this}}>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"{{}}" appears to be the solution

I can't find documentation on it, but it works in v0.5 and is used in existing polymer components (core-a11y-keys)

Answer (score 0):

I think no. When a new instance of a polymer element is created, scope for template is the element instance and expressions are evaluated using this scope. So, {{this}} is evaluated using the element instance and expected to be a property on model.

Comment: I was hoping for more of a definitive response - ideally from a polymer team member.  Either that, or an explanation of how they expect the scenario to be handled.  It seems like such an obvious gap, it's hard to believe they haven't run into this when building the component library.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the expression scopes section of the Polymer 0.5 documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/expressions.html#expression-scopes), you can use an empty binding expression: `"{{}}"`. Note that this hasn't been documented in Polymer 1.0, so no guarantees, but it appears to still be working.

```
<polymer-element name="my-el">
  <template>
    <sub-element target="{{}}"></sub-element>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

Alternatively, you can use the `parentElement` attribute which all polymer elements have. [Here's an example](https://www.polymer-project.org/articles/spa.html#keyboard) from the documentation for using core-a11y-keys for keyboard navigation. Using `parentElement' would look like this:

```
<polymer-element name="my-el">
  <template>
    <sub-element target="{{parentElement}}"></sub-element>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

Be careful with `parentElement` though. If you move the element, its parent could change.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  While I agree that this would solve the simple example I used, it doesn't actually solve the problem - how to get/pass the value of an element.  Worse (for me) it requires making the sub-element aware of, and dependent on, its position relative to a parent element, creating lots of future hair-pulling.  A cleaner workaround would probably be to create an attribute that returns the value of 'this' - it just seems like an awkward oversight